# jQuery $.post sends vars correct, but PHP receives nothing

Tags: php, jquery, post

I have this jQuery script that sends a username an password to a PHP file which checks if this user exists and returns a JSON user object. Works fine in non-IE browsers, but IE fails.

The wierd thing is that the IE "firebug" says everything is fine, but the PHP script doesnt recieve any vars...

**This is the request body:**

> username=johanderowan&password=1234

**These are the request headers (I left out a few vars for security reasons):**

> Request    = POST /1.0/account/login.json HTTP/1.1
>   Accept  = **/**
>   Origin  = [DEVURL]
>   Accept-Language = nl-NL
>   UA-CPU  = AMD64
>   Accept-Encoding = gzip, deflate
>   User-Agent = Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; Trident/5.0)
>   Host = [DEVURL]
>   Content-Length = 66
>   Connection  Keep-Alive
>   Cache-Control   no-cache

**The response body is (first three empty arrays are $_GET, $_POST and $_REQUEST):**

> Array
>   (
>   )
>   Array
>   (
>   )
>   Array
>   (
>   )
>   {"status":"error","message":"No username or password specified.","httpCode":500}

**This is the request script:**

```
$('.mobyNowLoginForm form').bind('submit', function(){  
    var username = $(this).find('.username').val();  
    var password = $(this).find('.password').val();  
    $.post('[url]/1.0/account/login.json', {
        username: username,
        password: password
    }, function(response) {
        // do something
    }, "JSON");  
    return false;
});
```

I have no clue at all what could be wrong here...

Comment: How did you get the HTTP response header and body?

Comment: WHat does `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));` show you? And what is `Content-Type` in the request headers?

Comment: One thing for sure is, the request header missed the `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. Maybe that's why PHP doesn't populate the request body to `$_POST`.

Comment: FWIW, the only way I can get jQuery to omit a `Content-Type` header and not send *any* POST variables is if the `data` parameter is either missing or contains attributes which are all `undefined` (this doesn't explain how you can see the request body being populated, but explains everything else). Try `alert`ing the values of `username`/`password`.

Comment: This is more a question: You post to login.json, not to login.php

Comment: @djot: me thinks that if the OP can see the dumps from the php superglobals & a custom error message, arriving at the php file is not part of the problem (and cool uri's are not implementation-dependent...)...

Comment: @Wrikken Well, I never posted to .json PHP files ;) ... and still don't know a answer and could be totally wrong, BUT it looks to me if the php script gets terminated with errors, so the PHP file is indeed not processed correctly. The "response" given also shows a HTTP 500 error.

Comment: @djot: url has little to do with actual file the requests ends up in (my php files are all called something.php, none of them is mentioned by anything-ending-in.php on the big bad outside internet).. As PHP never will produce json-encoded errors we can deduce that the error returned is by php-code running correctly (and the error generated is by design by the op's code), but complaining about bad input. So, request arriving OK, processing OK (although logic may be off), the only problem is a unmet expectation about input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that IE doesn't send a correct conent-type in cross-domain requests. The content-type is always set to "text/plain".

Read more about this shortcoming in this blogpost: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

We fixed this on the server by parsing the php://input string and setting this as $_POST vars.

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && count($_POST) == 0) {
    $postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $postVars = explode('&', $postData);
    foreach ($postVars as $postVar) {
        list($key, $var) = explode('=', $postVar);
        $_POST[$key] = $var;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good catch, I'd use `parse_str($postData,$_POST);` in that instance though, for input like `array[]=foo&array[]=bar`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set cache to false. I've had a similar problem and this fixed it:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '[url]/1.0/account/login.json',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
      username: username,
      password: password
  },
  cache: false,
  success: function() {
      // Do something
  }
});
```

I hope this helps you!

Steffen

**Edit**

> The problem could also be in your request URL. Your trying to make a call to a .json file.  You could try to make a call to a .php file instead.

Make sure you put this in your .php file:

```
header("Content-Type: application/json");
```